# I2C device detected on arduino and raspberry pi 3 but not on raspberry pi 4

Tags: pi-4, i2c

I have a fresh installation of raspbian (Linux raspberrypi 5.4.51-v7l+ #1333 SMP Mon Aug 10 16:51:40 BST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux) on a raspberry pi 4. I have enabled i2c and nothing else. I have connected an i2c device as shown below:

[image]

on the target device brown is SCL and red is SDA.

As you can see I power my r-pi through the 5V pin.

boot config:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
```

Reading i2c shows no result:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Using the same setup (except powering through USB and not VIN) on a raspberry pi 3 with the same SD card or an arduino works as expected and the device shows up.

Comment: are you sure you have enabled the I2C thing?

Comment: Yes, actually I did some further digging and took an old r-pi 3 and inserted my sd card that I used in the r-pi 4 and the devices show up. That is weird...

Comment: Ah, let me summarize. (1) Your Rpi4B SD card inserted into Rp3 works OK, can detect I2C devices. (2) Are you really using the ***CH341 USB to I2C adapter***?, If yes, then you might be in big trouble, because the kernels/drivers are not up to date enough. Moreover, Rpi4B USB3 is not very compatible. So, TRY USB2 socket/hub first. I often found USB3 related setup doesn't work, and USB2 works happily. I agree that the problem is not related to raspbian or any config, it is only related to USB3 kernel/drivers.

Comment: Note, I have little experience in CH341 or PL2012 USB drivers. I only know that recent CH341 is better than PL, but PL might take over very soon. This version problem is annoying, but exist for a very long time. Good luck. Cheers.

Comment: I have the module installed but currently my tests are over the normal SDA and SCL pins of both the 4 and 3 and the adapter is also not plugged in.

Comment: I am a little bit confused. Do your mean you are using the Rpi4B on board built in hardware TxD/RxD pins BroardCom GPIO numbering pins 15/14?. For Rpi4B, there are more than one pair of UART pins, perhaps you can try UART1, UART2 etc. But don't go too far up, usually the multiple UART/SPI/I2C port crashed after two or three ports. But again, I am just messing around, configuring DT drivers, never dare going deeper

Comment: Of course last resort is using a fresh SD card, without installing any third party drivers.

Comment: If you want help provide a clear photo showing the connections AND include a listing of `/boot/config.txt`

Comment: Due to the new findings I have completely rewritten my question basically to provide a minimal example.

Comment: By now my temporary conclusion is that the i2c is broken on my r-pi due to applying incorrect voltage at some point. Once I am going to remove it from its location I will be able to verify this.